# How to use sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest & sinon.fakeServer.create in NodeJS environment

Tags: node.js, sinon

In my project there is a requirement to execute test scripts in NodeJS environment. In test script i want to use sinon's useFakeXMLHttpRequest & fakeServer.

Is it possible to use this in NodeJS environment.

Any help is appreciated..